# Check Role of user in spree Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have 2 roles
 1. user
 2. Gatekeeper

my database is like this

table:spree_roles_users
fields:
role_id
user_id

Both users and gatekeeper have rights to create new visitor,
but on index page it should display visitors which are entered by gatekeeper only
so how to check role of user_id

example:

There is a society say "My society"
There are 5 users who are registered from My society ,3 users have "User" role, 1 user have "admin" role, and 1 user has "Gatekeeper" role.
All 5 of them can save Visitors form, but in index page,only those visitors should b visible which are entered by person with "Gatekeeper" role.
So how to check Id_user with spree_roles_users
so visitors entered by Gatekeeper should b visible

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be more interested in Solidus (a fork of Spree) which has received a *lot* of work pertaining to permissions inside of Spree. The permissions are managed by CanCan and you can find them located inside of permission helpers.

https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/tree/master/core/lib/spree/permission_sets

Spree is not that mature when discussing permissions...

Comment: I am using cancan, i have already applied permissions, roles are saved in spree_roles_users , and my users are saved in spree_users , when a user inputs a data, it should save with the role of user, my question is related to relational database and a code line in rails

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the question. Can you update with more information?